# Change subtype in Hibernate Inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, playframework

I have three classes I want to model using Hibernate in Play!Framework:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class SupplyArea extends Model {
    public int scadaId;
    public String symbol;
}

@Entity
public class HighVoltageSubstation extends SupplyArea {
    public int hvAttribute;
}

@Entity
public class MediumVoltageSubstation extends SupplyArea {
    public int mvAttribute;
}
```

Thanks to Play! I already have defined primary key identifier id.

It works fine most of the time: I've got three database tables, HVSubstation and MVSubstation identifiers are created as foreign keys to SupplyArea and so on.

But I don't 'own' the objects, I need to import them from another source. Then, if something changes in another application, I need to update mine. The problem is when the object changes its type: it is no more a HVSubstation, it is now a MVSubstation. All other parameters (ie. scadaId, symbol) remain the same. It is the same object, but has another type.

Is there any way to switch between subtypes without losing my primary key identifier? I tried something like this:

```
SupplyArea oldArea = SupplyArea.getByScadaId(scadaId); // returns HVSubstation
SupplyArea newArea = new MVSubstation();
newArea.id = oldArea.id;
newArea.scadaId = scadaId;
newArea.symbol = symbol;
oldArea.delete();
newArea.save();
```

Obviously, it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the substations can change from high to medium voltage (or back), I would not model these as separate subtypes. Instead, I would just use a single SubStation type with a property to determine whether it's high or medium voltage. In Hibernate, that would map to a single table with a discriminator property.

Comment: It is not a good idea, I'm afraid. There are more subtypes than these two I mentioned.
And switching the type between them is not someone would do all the time - it would rather be a 'fix typo' issue in the source application. But for me, all these subtypes have completely different sets of additional attributes.

Comment: @Umberto, OK, if switching type is the exception rather than the norm, my solution above does not apply. I don't think you can do it (i.e. migrating data from one table to another while reusing the primary key) within Hibernate. Your best bet may be to use a stored procedure to do the dirty job. Then you must take care of invalidating any stale cached data.

Comment: It's a pity. Well, we can't always work on a top level of our code, right? ;) Thanks for your help!