# JPA Inheritance Type JOINED Update (changing subtype)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

The context of the problem is a product management system for CRUD operations. Common product properties are the same for all products, each concrete product type has some additional fields. 
When the user selects the product type, the additional fields are dynamically loaded.

I'm using JPA and have the following inheritance using InheritanceType.JOINED:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class AbstractProduct { ... }

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
public class ProductA extends AbstractProduct { ... }

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
public class ProductB extends AbstractProduct { ... }
```

Further on I use JpaRepositories for the CRUD operations.

It works fine for CRUD operation, except when the user wants to change the type of a product. If I have read an oject of type ProductA, is there any possibility to use the JPA update functions to change the product type to ProductB?

*edit*: When using the repository to save the update, the old entry is not updated (e.g. removing the entry from ProductA, updating the entry in AbstractProduct, inserting the entry in ProductB), instead i tries to insert a new (additional) object.

Comment: related/equal to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617398/change-subtype-in-hibernate-inheritance